# Error while trying to Build make file

Tags: java, makefile

I am trying to learn JNI by myself... and I am getting stuck again and again due to lack of proper guidance.
I am following JNI tutorials for eclipse(2.4  JNI in Eclipse) from [This Link](https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/JavaNativeInterface.html) and following the step 3, I am getting the following error while trying to build makefile::

```
mingw32-make HelloJNI.h   
javah   -classpath  C:/Users/Lenovo/MyWorkspace/HelloJNI/bin    HelloJNI
makefile:4: recipe for target 'HelloJNI.h' failed
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, javah -classpath C:/Users/Lenovo/MyWorkspace/HelloJNI/bin HelloJNI, ...) failed.
make (e=2): The system cannot find the file specified.
mingw32-make:  [HelloJNI.h] Error 2
```

[Error As seen in eclipse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/udkIy.png)...

I tried to build makefile via CMD,but then also its showing the same error.
Please help me to solve this...

Comment: Looks like you are missing some packages, or have an incorrect setup; you may try to use gradle, it has very good native tool support

Comment: You should include the relevant parts of your sources -at least the `Makefile`- too, not just a link to them.

Comment: Can You tell me how to do that?

Comment: Hi Everyone, for someone with little knowledge as me; This will be a good start; easy and not at all mesyy : http://codeandme.blogspot.ae/2011/09/jni-made-easy.html